# Using a variable range to select columns in R

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a dataset containing several columns with similar colnames. Each variable has multiple measurements, resulting in multiple columns. These are in the form of:
mt1_oranges_vol, mt2_oranges_vol, mt3_oranges_vol; mt1_pears_vol, mt2_pears_vol, mt3_pears_vol, etc.

```
      dataset <- structure(
  list(
    Participant.Id = 1:5,
    
    x1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L),
    x2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L),
    x3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, NA),
    x4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA),
    x5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, NA),
    x6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA),
    
    y1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L),
    y2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L),
    y3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, NA),
    y4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA),
    y5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, NA),
    y6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA),
    
    z1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L),
    z2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L),
    z3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, NA),
    z4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA),
    z5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, NA),
    z6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA),
    
    mt1_oranges_vol = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L),
    mt2_oranges_vol = c(110L, 210L, 310L, 410L, 510L),
    mt3_oranges_vol = c(120L, 220L, NA, 420L, 520L),
    mt4_oranges_vol = c(130L, 230L, NA, 430L, NA),
    mt5_oranges_vol = c(NA, 240L, NA, NA, NA),
    mt6_oranges_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
     
    mt1_pears_vol = c(101L, 201L, 301L, 401L, 501L),
    mt2_pears_vol = c(111L, 211L, 311L, 411L, 511L),
    mt3_pears_vol = c(121L, 221L, NA, 421L, 521L),
    mt4_pears_vol = c(131L, 231L, NA, 431L, NA),
    mt5_pears_vol = c(NA, 241L, NA, NA, NA),
    mt6_pears_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),

    mt1_apples_vol = c(102L, 202L, 302L, 402L, 502L),
    mt2_apples_vol = c(112L, 212L, 312L, 412L, 512L),
    mt3_apples_vol = c(122L, 222L, NA, 422L, 522L),
    mt4_apples_vol = c(132L, 232L, NA, 432L, NA),
    mt5_apples_vol = c(NA, 242L, NA, NA, NA),
    mt6_apples_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),


  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L)
)
```

Now, Now I simply select the variables using

```
   dataset <- dataset%>% 
   select(Participant.Id,
         matches("_vol$"))
```

However, I want to be able to only include specific columns based on a variable:

```
mt_range <- x:y #x:y is a predefined range of numbers
```

I have tried things such as:

```
dataset <- dataset%>% 
     select(Participant.Id,
     matches(paste0("mt", mt_range, "_vol"))
```

However, this does not provide the desired outcome. My understanding is that it will paste 1:7 as a whole because I am not iterating over the numbers, just adding the variable. I tried using:

```
  dataset <- dataset %>% 
       select(Participant.Id,
             for (i in mt range){
                        matches(paste0("mt", i, "_vol"))
                        }
```

However, from my understanding you can't loop within a function. Additionally, this would give mt1:7_vol I think, however I need it to also take into considerdation the different variables names.

So, my question is:

How could I implement the use of mt_range to only get those variables that I am interested in.

If anything is missing or my question is asked incorrectly, please let me know and I will change it.

Comment: I would suggest you instead pivot the data to long format - you can then very easily filter with whatever complexity you require.  See: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse the range and make that a string to match on. For example:

```r
mt_range <- 3:5

# Use this regex
sprintf("^mt[%s]_.+_vol$", paste(mt_range, collapse = ""))
# [1] "^mt[345]_.+_vol$"
```

This will match all strings which start with `"mt"` and are followed by any character in the range `"[345]"` followed by an underscore, then any set of characters (`".+"`), if the string ends with `"_vol"`.

You can make this into a one-line function:

```r
mt_range_builder <- \(x) sprintf("^mt[%s]_.+_vol$", paste(x, collapse = ""))
```

```r
dataset |>
    select(
        Participant.Id,
        matches(
            mt_range_builder(mt_range)
        )
    )

#   Participant.Id mt3_oranges_vol mt4_oranges_vol mt5_oranges_vol mt3_pears_vol mt4_pears_vol mt5_pears_vol mt3_apples_vol mt4_apples_vol mt5_apples_vol
# 1              1             120             130              NA           121           131            NA            122            132             NA
# 2              2             220             230             240           221           231           241            222            232            242
# 3              3              NA              NA              NA            NA            NA            NA             NA             NA             NA
# 4              4             420             430              NA           421           431            NA            422            432             NA
# 5              5             520              NA              NA           521            NA            NA            522             NA             NA
```

A more general function might be:

```r
range_builder <- function(prefix, range, suffix) {
    sprintf(
        "^%s[%s]_.+_%s$",
        prefix,
        paste(range, collapse = ""),
        suffix
    )
}

range_builder("mt", 3:5, "vol") == mt_range_builder(3:5) # TRUE
```

Comment: It works amazingly, thank you! The only issue is that I also have a variable mt10 which is included for some reason, do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: @y.a yes - just needed a slightly stricter regex with an extra underscore. I've edited - this should exclude mt10 now.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Now I had a secondary question, but I am not sure if I have to ask another question on the forum or just here, but ill risk it. I now also want to calculate the total of each measurement. so for ct1_apples+ct1_pears+ct1_oranges; ct2_apples, ct2pears etc. For now I have done it as mutate(mt1_total_vol = rowSums(select(., starts_with("mt1_")), na.rm = F),
       mt2_total_vol = rowSums(select(., starts_with("mt2_")), na.rm = F),
       mt3_total_vol = rowSums(select(., starts_with("mt3_")), na.rm = F). To shorten it, I tried for loops and Across, with no succes

Comment: @y.a you probably want `dataset |> rowwise() |> mutate(mt1_total = sum(c_across(starts_with("mt1")), na.rm = TRUE))` but I would suggest putting the data in long form for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases it's much easier to `reshape` to long format instead of using your current wide format.

Firstly, though, you should definitely get into the habit of using the tenses as the usual suffixes instead of prefixes. This can easily be done using `grep` to identify the critical *mt* column names. We use `strsplit` at the underscores, rearrange and `paste` back together.

```
mt <- grep('^mt', names(dataset))
names(dataset)[mt] <- strsplit(names(dataset)[mt], '_') |> sapply(\(x) paste(x[c(2, 3, 1)], collapse='_'))
```

The names now look like this: t1_oranges_vol, mt2_oranges_vol, ...

Next `reshape`,

```
dataset_lng <- reshape(dataset, idvar=1, varying=-1, direction='long', sep='')
```

and `subset` for desired `mt_range`.

```
    Participant.Id time  x  y  z oranges_vol_mt pears_vol_mt apples_vol_mt
1.2              1    2 15 15 15            110          111           112
2.2              2    2 25 25 25            210          211           212
3.2              3    2 35 35 35            310          311           312
4.2              4    2 45 45 45            410          411           412
5.2              5    2 55 55 55            510          511           512
1.3              1    3 20 20 20            120          121           122
2.3              2    3 25 25 25            220          221           222
3.3              3    3 NA NA NA             NA           NA            NA
4.3              4    3 45 45 45            420          421           422
5.3              5    3 NA NA NA            520          521           522
1.4              1    4 25 25 25            130          131           132
2.4              2    4 30 30 30            230          231           232
3.4              3    4 NA NA NA             NA           NA            NA
4.4              4    4 50 50 50            430          431           432
5.4              5    4 NA NA NA             NA           NA            NA
1.5              1    5 NA NA NA             NA           NA            NA
2.5              2    5 35 35 35            240          241           242
3.5              3    5 NA NA NA             NA           NA            NA
4.5              4    5 55 55 55             NA           NA            NA
5.5              5    5 NA NA NA             NA           NA            NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dataset)
structure(list(Participant.Id = 1:5, x1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L), x2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L), x3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, 
NA), x4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA), x5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, 
NA), x6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA), y1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L), y2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L), y3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, 
NA), y4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA), y5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, 
NA), y6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA), z1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L), z2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L), z3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, 
NA), z4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA), z5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, 
NA), z6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA), mt1_oranges_vol = c(100L, 200L, 
300L, 400L, 500L), mt2_oranges_vol = c(110L, 210L, 310L, 410L, 
510L), mt3_oranges_vol = c(120L, 220L, NA, 420L, 520L), mt4_oranges_vol = c(130L, 
230L, NA, 430L, NA), mt5_oranges_vol = c(NA, 240L, NA, NA, NA
), mt6_oranges_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mt1_pears_vol = c(101L, 
201L, 301L, 401L, 501L), mt2_pears_vol = c(111L, 211L, 311L, 
411L, 511L), mt3_pears_vol = c(121L, 221L, NA, 421L, 521L), mt4_pears_vol = c(131L, 
231L, NA, 431L, NA), mt5_pears_vol = c(NA, 241L, NA, NA, NA), 
    mt6_pears_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mt1_apples_vol = c(102L, 
    202L, 302L, 402L, 502L), mt2_apples_vol = c(112L, 212L, 312L, 
    412L, 512L), mt3_apples_vol = c(122L, 222L, NA, 422L, 522L
    ), mt4_apples_vol = c(132L, 232L, NA, 432L, NA), mt5_apples_vol = c(NA, 
    242L, NA, NA, NA), mt6_apples_vol = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of a pivot-longer approach:

```
library(tidyverse) # you could load individual packages as a better practice
dataset <- dataset |> pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("vol"),
                        names_to = c("mt_vol", "fruit", NA),
                        names_sep = "_") |> 
  mutate(mt_vol = as.numeric(str_extract(mt_vol,"\\d+")))
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 90 × 22
   Participant.Id    x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    x6    y1    y2    y3    y4    y5    y6    z1    z2    z3    z4    z5    z6 mt_vol fruit   value
            <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <chr>   <int>
 1              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      1 oranges   100
 2              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      2 oranges   110
 3              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      3 oranges   120
 4              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      4 oranges   130
 5              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      5 oranges    NA
 6              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      6 oranges    NA
 7              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      1 pears     101
 8              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      2 pears     111
 9              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      3 pears     121
10              1    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA    10    15    20    25    NA    NA      4 pears     131
# … with 80 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Then very easy filtering/selecting ensues.

```
mt_range <- 3:5

dataset |>
  filter(mt_vol %in% mt_range) |>
  select(Participant.Id, mt_vol, fruit, value)
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 45 × 4
   Participant.Id mt_vol fruit   value
            <int>  <dbl> <chr>   <int>
 1              1      3 oranges   120
 2              1      4 oranges   130
 3              1      5 oranges    NA
 4              1      3 pears     121
 5              1      4 pears     131
 6              1      5 pears      NA
 7              1      3 apples    122
 8              1      4 apples    132
 9              1      5 apples     NA
10              2      3 oranges   220
# … with 35 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

You can then pivot them back wider if needed.